# Flutter: should I use other variable names for 'internal' BuildContexts?

Tags: flutter, scope, android-context, builder

It has just recently come to my attention, that in many cases, such as when using a `FutureBuilder` or calling `showDialog()`, we have to define a builder which takes a `BuildContext` as an argument, and that `BuildContext` (might) be a different one than the `BuildContext` in the surrounding scope.

In this first code snippet, I have two different `BuildContext`s that have the same variable name:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: myFuture,
    builder: (context, snapshot) { //this and the surrounding context have the same name, but my code works without problems
      //... assume that for some reason, I need to access context here
    },
  );
}
```

My question is, would it be recommended, or is it even necessary, to give those 'inner' `BuildContext`s ANOTHER variable name? Such as in this example from my code:

```
void _showConfirmDialog(BuildContext context) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) { //I maybe had to rename it bc of a bug, can't remember
      return AlertDialog(
          //...
      );
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: If you are sure, that you won't be using some variables you can omit their names.
Then you will have (_, __) => yourWidget(builder: (context) => ...)
You can apply this inside every function, builder, method, anything.

Comment: On the other hand, you can specify better name for inside contexts somehow like "mainContext", "widgetContext", "ctx", "otherInnerWIdgetContext".

Comment: @DavidSedlář and if I want to show a SnackBar, which requires a BuildContext as an argument, I would just use the uppermost context or like you said "mainContext", right? Or would there be a scenario in which I'd rather use an inner context?

Comment: If you would for example render some bottom sheet, which function would require its context, and now you will have mainContext and modalContext, you need to call the one you want your SnackBar to be attached to. If you will call mainContext with open modal, your SnackBar might be under the modal and not visible. If you will call it with  modalContext it will be rendered properly.

Comment: @DavidSedlář thank you so much David, that makes sense to me :)